# Write Metadata object to an XML file

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

Edit: Rephrased entire question.

Hi,

I am writing a Java program to analyze some metadata on Salesforce and also modify some files.

I am trying to read a metadata file of type Profile into Profile object Salesforce provides:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm

I was able to do so by the following code: 
http://paste.ofcode.org/CRZMZsfcwdTmXz4zzCwJqY

When I want to modify the metadata. e.g. add Field Permission etc. and save it into an XML file back again. I am using this code:
http://paste.ofcode.org/fZQZaGu3DMjfsHdndwq2WD

However, the output is different than what I downloaded from Salesforce.

Source from Salesforce:
http://paste.ofcode.org/tq6S48VyHx7MJFtai5ZqUM

Output from my app:
http://paste.ofcode.org/FnRSMfNrsM4CrEQ5e9Nc5Y

Please assist :)
Thanks !

Comment: @sfdcfox
Could you please help? :)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I wrote any Java code, but I think the XML output is appending a default namespace, I cribbed this form [stackexchange.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068901/xmloutputstream-repairing-namespaces-and-attributes-without-namespaces) which may be of use:

```
String nsURI = "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata";
XMLOutputFactory outF = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
outF.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory.IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES, true);
XMLStreamWriter out = outF.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
out.setDefaultNamespace(nsURI);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The write method on the profile object expects an XmlOutputStream. I get a compilation error when I provide something else. I am using the XmlOutputStram from the WSC